# Strip oddly formatted IPs out of a CSV with Powershell

Tags: bash, powershell, csv

Grizzly Steppe identified IPs, signatures and the like were released to the public in [this CSV document.](https://www.us-cert.gov/sites/default/files/publications/JAR-16-20296A.csv) I used the following to pull out the IPs to compare with our firewall logs in the past.

```
cut -f1 -d',' -s JAR-16-20296A.csv |egrep ^[0-9].*\][0-9*]$|tr -d "[]"| tr '\n' ' '
```

This resulted in the output:

```
128.199.108.0 89.32.40.4 146.0.74.7 89.45.67.6 91.1.1.1 62.1.1.1 5.212.1.1 1.112.1.1 42.1.1.1 43.1.1.1 41.212.1.1 1.212.1.1 46.165.197.1 207.176.226.8 66.158.142.2 103.244.164.3 115.238.95.4 103.226.132.7 5.34.150.2 217.13.56.9 147.102.10.1 103.254.108.7 103.38.193.6 85.24.197.4 202.28.194.6 122.147.230.8 65.36.205.1 128.146.176.6 69.89.191.8 186.215.192.2 140.130.213.5 203.157.155.8 46.165.230.5 50.7.176.2 51.254.215.7 51.255.33.0 69.162.139.9 88.80.7.5 89.31.57.5 91.146.121.3 109.163.234.5 109.163.234.8 163.172.29.9 185.34.33.2 185.104.120.2 185.104.120.4 185.104.120.7 193.15.16.4 198.96.155.3 217.13.197.5 109.163.234.2 109.188.125.3 109.188.125.4 109.188.125.5 109.188.125.9 173.246.103.8 178.162.205.2 204.194.29.4 37.187.239.8 37.187.247.3 64.137.178.3 92.222.88.7 94.198.100.8 94.242.57.2
```

How would I get the same results in PowerShell?

Comment: `-join((ipcsv JAR-16-20296A.csv|% INDICATOR_VALUE|?{$_ -match '^[0-9].*\][0-9*]$'}) -replace '[\[\]]')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command results in a similar output

```
Import-Csv '.\JAR-16-20296A.csv' | 
    Where-Object{$_.indicator_value -match '^[0-9].*\][0-9*]$'} | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty indicator_value | 
    ForEach-Object { $_  -replace '[\[\]]'}
```

1. Use Import-Csv to load the file
2. filter to only the records matching the regex expression
3. Get only the indicator_value field
4. remove [ and ] (Credit to @mathias-r-jessen for a more PowerShell way of doing this I borrowed from his comment.)

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thanks! Pushed my skills forward a few notches.

Comment: I would filter on `$_.type -eq 'ipv4addr'` and skip the `Select-Object` (`ForEach-Object { $_.indicator_value -replace '[\[\]]' }`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, I'm not sure I understand where you'd add that filter. Could you toss your version up as an answer? Seems like that is sufficiently different to warrant its own addition.

Comment: @flickerfly It's just minor adjustments, really. You'd use the filter instead of `$_.indicator_value -match ...`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Pathfile="c:\temp\JAR-16-20296A.csv"


#explicit version
Import-Csv $Pathfile | Where INDICATOR_VALUE -Match "^[0-9].*\][0-9*]$" | Select {$_.INDICATOR_VALUE.Replace("[.]", ".")}

#short version
ipcsv $Pathfile  | ? I* -Match "^[0-9].*\][0-9*]$" | % {$_.INDICATOR_VALUE.Replace("[.]", ".")}
```

Comment: Thanks for the two different versions. The comparison is informative.